# Getting wrong output from summation

Tags: c, c++11

I have just set up VS code for C++ today and I tried to check if everything works perfectly. First I tried to print "Hello World" and it worked. Then I wrote this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x = 10, y = 20, z;
    z = x + y;
    printf("%d + %d = %d", &x, &y, &z);
    return 0;
}
```

After running that simple code, I got an output:
`6422220 + 6422216 = 6422212`

What did go wrong?

Comment: `&x, &y, &z` -> `x, y, z`

Comment: For `scanf` the arguments must be pointers (which you get with the pointer-to operator `&`) but not for `printf`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I want to know, then why am I getting an output like that? wasn't I supposed to get an error message?

Comment: @eishaenan `&` returns the address of a variable.

Comment: On most system, a pointer is just a plain integer that's handled specially by the language and the system. Modern versions of the big three compilers (MSVC, GCC and CLang) all are able to detect this though, and emit a warning about it. You might have to add extra flags when building to enable these warnings, and then treat them as errors. For e.g. GCC and Clang use at least `-Wall`, but I also recommend `-Wextra` and `-Wpedantic`. For MSVC use `/W4`.

Comment: Always compile with at least `-Wall -Wextra`. IMO, they should make those standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are printing the addresses of `x`, `y` and `z` here

```
printf("%d + %d = %d", &x, &y, &z);
```

This will print the values

```
printf("%d + %d = %d", x, y, z);
```

Answer (score 0):

You setup your VS code for c++ but you write a C program?
taking about your output it's showing correct because you are printing the address of variable x, y and z.
(&) - this is a reference operator. it is used for accessing the address.
suppose x is your variable the &x is the address of variable x.